# Don't know how to build task 'rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I'm following Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Rails 5) Learn Web Development with Rails
Michael Hartl, using rails 5.0.0.1, when I tried to run the following command in bash

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

I received this error

```
Version: 1.7.2

Usage: spring COMMAND [ARGS]

Commands for spring itself:

  binstub         Generate spring based binstubs. Use --all to generate a binstub for all known commands. Use --remove to revert.
  help            Print available commands.
  server          Explicitly start a Spring server in the foreground
  status          Show current status.
  stop            Stop all spring processes for this project.

Commands for your application:

  rails           Run a rails command. The following sub commands will use spring: console, runner, generate, destroy, test.
  rake            Runs the rake command
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rails' (see --tasks)
/home/Medo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:13:in `block in run_rake_task'
/home/Medo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:10:in `run_rake_task'
/home/Medo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/home/Medo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:9:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I don't know what causing this issue and can't see a solution for it after hour of searching.

Comment: Try to run `spring rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string`

Comment: same thing as above  but without the error message of rails aborted!

Comment: I am not sure enough because I don't use spring but can you try my answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well this what worked for me

`bundle install --binstubs`

after it, rails worked without a problem

Comment: This solved the rails g and rails c problem for me, nice!

Answer (score 3):

This is what help give us. I just run this 3 commands and it's work.

> Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by
>   Bundler.
>
> In Rails 5, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are
>   versioned like any other source code, rather than stubs that are
>   generated on demand.
>
> Here's how to upgrade:
>
> bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
>   rails app:update:bin          # Use the new Rails 5 executables
>   git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control
>
> You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but maybe it can help

```
$ spring stop
$ rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

Comment: I get spring is not running when I type spring stop and when I try rails generate I get the same error message

Comment: Have you tried `bundle exec rails generate ...` or `bin/rails generate` if you have binstub?

Comment: yes same thing, always says ```Don't know how to build task 'rails'```

Comment: spring seems to cause rails command issues on macos, I'm used to `spring stop` once a month, it works much better then

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if rails s is working.Also try

```
bin/rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```